# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, type, text

Deseo limpiar TODOS los campos del formulario que sean de tipo "text", me funciona correctamente pero en la consola me sale el siguiente error:

```
formulario.js:175 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

**Código:**

```
function limpiar(){
    var cajas_texto = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; cajas_texto.length; i++)
        if(cajas_texto[i].type == "text")
            cajas_texto[i].value="";    
}
```

Comment: el for está bien escrito?

Comment: Madre mía, no me había fijado jajajajaj. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estabas accediendo a una posición de la lista que tenía valores sin definir debido a un error en el for

```
function limpiar(){
    var cajas_texto = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i < cajas_texto.length; i++)
        if(cajas_texto[i].type == "text")
            cajas_texto[i].value="";    
}
```

Comment: ¡¿No creo que ahí esté el error...?! Con controlar lo que me interesa debería funcionar. Si quiere controlar únicamente los de tipo "text" para cambiarles el valor, sería suficente. Los demás "inputs" no los modifico para nada.

Comment: El error te está diciendo que intenta acceder a una propiedad type sobre un elemento undefined. El único lugar en el código donde accedes a una propiedad type es en el if dentro del for

Comment: Te he puesto la opción en el códgo, el for está mal, crea un bloque que accede a posiciones undefined. Y además evita que alguna posición no definida del array intente acceder al elemento tipo

Comment: Me faltó definir "i<"... perdón.

Comment: Yo te voté positivamente, yo no fui.